# How does fall planted garlic cope with snow, and freezing temperatures?

Tags: temperature, garlic

Last fall I planted garlic, and it has a few leaves sticking out of the ground now. How will this effect the leaves?

Comment: Many perennial plants have all the growth above ground killed off every winter. So long as the garlic bulb survives it will regrow next year. In fact garlic *requires* 4 to 8 weeks of low winter temperatures to grow well.

Comment: it's just a spring snow storm after we've had all the snow melted.a couple weeks ago

Comment: Your question was very unclear The obvious way to read it is that it was a question about how garlic survives over winter. But I guess everybody around the world who uses this site is going to know you just had a late snow storm, without being told! If plants curled up and died because of a bit of unseasonal weather, there wouldn't *be* any plants.

Comment: it's comming up just fine now that we have warmer temps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have no fear, black thumb. I've grown garlic for years and it's always survived spring snows with no damage. Last year, we had 3-4 inches in very late April and the garlic shrugged it off. It was up a good 4 inches or more, too. There was no effect on the leaves or final crop. I've even had it green up in November and had the leaves survive the winter with only minimial damage, as long as it was covered by snow during the coldest months and we had a warmish winter (no 20 below temps).